How to formally refer to equivalence classes *within* a class?
Strictly speaking, when speaking of classes (say within $\mathsf{ZFC}$), we really are referring to formulae. Thus, a class $C$ may be thought of as a formula $\phi(x) \in \mathcal{L}_{\mathsf{ZFC}}$, and when we speak of things like $x \in C$ we really just mean that $\phi(x)$ (i.e., $x$ verifies $\phi(x)$). (Similarly, class intersection may be conceived through formulae conjunction, class union through formulae disjunction, etc.) My question now is: What if I want to speak of equivalence classes of a certain class?
From what I've heard, "Scott's trick" can work in such situations, say when you are looking to speak of cardinals as ordinal equivalence classes and so need a representative for each all (same with order types, etc.) Can this trick be used in general? Say I'm working with all graphs under $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (hence with the class $\phi(x) \equiv \text{$x$ is a graph}$) and I define some sort of isomorphism equivalence relation $\sim$. Is there now some way to speak of the graph equivalence classes formed under $\sim$? Or do I need instead to go the metatheoretic route and quotient the subset $\{m \in M : \mathcal{M} \models \phi(\overline{m})\}$ of some model $\mathcal{M} = \langle M, \in_M \rangle$ by $\sim$ and work with that?

I believe that there is a general way to select a canonical representative, some kind of "least representative" in the von Neumann hierarchy, assuming such a representative exists. When one really needs such a representative, though, perhaps it's best to work out one's own construction of a set of representatives (I recently had to do this for a geometric group theory problem).

Another trick is to restrict $\phi(x)$ to a Grothendieck universe --- which is a set --- and then form your equivalence classes within that set.

@LeeMosher In general there is no "least representative" (unless you are working in something like the constructible universe $L$ so there is a canonical global well-ordering), but a set of least representatives; the "representative" for $x$ under $\sim$ is ${y\in V_\alpha:y\sim x}$ where $\alpha$ is the least for which the set is nonempty. This is exactly Scott's trick. I've never seen it mentioned anywhere, but I think in the usual construction of Tor and Ext groups by free resolution one also needs Scott's trick.

Ah, thanks! That's Scott's trick!
